# Perisistence Exception : No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit

Tags: java, playframework, persistence, hibernate-entitymanager

I am new to PLAY framework. I keep getting this error. I don't seem to find any problem with the code though. Please help me out.

conf/META-INF/persistence.xml:

```html
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

my application.conf:

```html
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
ebean.default="model.*" // cuz my folder is model and not models.
```

my call for entitymanager:

```html
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultPersistenceUnit");
```

Please help me out!